# Why do I get a segfault when the for loop finishes adding elements to a list?

Tags: c, list, segmentation-fault

My code is an algorithm to solve a problem related to the longest-job first. It receives the number of process (num_programas) and for each process it gets an time (instante) and a weight(carga). When i'm inserting on the list it inserts all process but in the last one it gets segmentation fault.

It is  sorting  normally (i've printed the header each time the loops executes), it just gets segmentation fault in the last execution of the for loop (for instance: num programas = 7, stops working when i = 6)

```
/*

Vou fazer com lista duplamente encadeada só pra facilitar na funcao proximo. Não vou otimizar porque preciso me livrar
logo pra fazer o projeto e estudar

puta merda que codigo horrivel, espero que o aleardo nao leia. Otimizar depois.


8
74 11 
7 20
53 17
78 13
52 11
63 19
89 17
15 20
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct processo
{
    int temp;
    int carga;
    struct processo *next;
    struct processo *prev;
};

struct processo *cadastrarProcesso(struct processo *header, int instante, int carga);
struct processo *executarAtividade(struct processo *header, int *tempo_executando);
struct processo *inserirProcessos(struct processo *programa, struct processo *header);
void imprimirLista(struct processo *header);
struct processo *proximo(struct processo *header, int *tempo_executando);

int main()
{
    struct processo *header, *aux;
    header = NULL;
    int num_programas, instante, carga, i, tempo_executando = 0;
    scanf("%d", &num_programas);
    for (i = 0; i < num_programas; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d %d", &instante, &carga);
        header = cadastrarProcesso(header, instante, carga);
    }
    /*
        Cadastrou e ordenou em ordem de tempo, aí tem que criar uma funcao para ir printando
    */

    imprimirLista(header);

    for (i = 0; i < num_programas; i++)
    {
        header = executarAtividade(header, &tempo_executando);
    }

    return 0;
}
struct processo *cadastrarProcesso(struct processo *header, int instante, int carga)
{
    struct processo *aux;
    aux = malloc(sizeof(struct processo));
    aux->next = NULL;
    aux->prev = NULL;
    aux->carga = carga;
    aux->temp = instante;
    header = inserirProcessos(aux, header);
    return header;
}
struct processo *inserirProcessos(struct processo *programa, struct processo *header)
{
    struct processo *aux;
    if (header == NULL)
    {
        header = programa;
        return header;
    }
    aux = header;
    while (aux->next != NULL && programa->temp > aux->temp)
    {
        aux = aux->next;
    }

    if (aux == header)
    {
        // tem que fazer essa verificacao pq ele sai do while tanto se o while->next for nulo e tambem se for maior
        if (programa->temp < aux->temp)
        {
            // insere depois do header, se tornando o novo header
            aux->prev = programa;
            programa->next = aux;
            return programa;
            // é o novo header, retorna ele
        }

        else // insere depois)
        {
            programa->next = aux->next;
            aux->next = programa;
            programa->prev = aux;

            return header;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // vamos ver se ele saiu porque while->next é nulo ou porque é maior
        if (programa->temp < aux->temp)
        {
            (aux->prev)->next = programa;
            programa->prev = aux->prev;
            programa->next = aux;
            aux->prev = programa;
            return header;
        }
        else // maior igual
        {
            programa->next = aux->next;
            programa->prev = aux;
            aux->next = programa;
            return header;
        }
    }
}

void imprimirLista(struct processo *header) // funcao auxiliar
{
    struct processo *aux;
    aux = header;
    while (aux != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", aux->temp);
        aux = aux->next;
    }
}

struct processo *executarAtividade(struct processo *header, int *tempo_executando)
{

    // lembrando que já está dentro de um for
    struct processo *aux;
    if (*tempo_executando == 0)
    {
        aux = header;
        *tempo_executando = aux->temp + aux->carga;
        header = aux->next;
        printf("%d ", aux->carga); // imprime a carga da saida que foi executada
        (aux->next)->prev = NULL;
        aux->next = NULL;
        free(aux);
        return header;
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: reduzir esse codigo zendo tudo dentro do mesmo IF, só olhando a condicao do proximo

        aux = proximo(header, tempo_executando); // recebe o que vai ser executado
        *tempo_executando = *tempo_executando + aux->carga;
        if (aux == header) // se o aux
        {
            header = aux->next;
            printf("%d ", aux->carga);
            (aux->next)->prev = NULL;
            aux->next = NULL;
            free(aux);
            return header;
        }
        else
        {

            if (aux->next != NULL)
            {
                (aux->next)->prev = aux->prev;
                (aux->prev)->next = aux->next;
            }
            else
            {
                (aux->prev)->next = aux->next;
            }
            printf("%d ", aux->carga);
            free(aux);
            return header;
        }
    }
}
struct processo *proximo(struct processo *header, int *tempo_executando)
{
    struct processo *aux, *escolhido;
    int maior_carga;
    aux = header;
    maior_carga = aux->carga;
    escolhido = aux;
    if (aux->temp >= *tempo_executando)
    {
        //*tempo_executando = *tempo_executando + (aux->temp - *tempo_executando);
        return aux;
    }
    else
    {
        while (aux->next != NULL && aux->temp < *tempo_executando)
        {
            aux = aux->next;

            if (aux->carga > maior_carga)
            {
                maior_carga = aux->carga;
                escolhido = aux;
            }
            else if (aux->carga == maior_carga)
            {
                // o critério de desempate é o menor tempo
                if (aux->carga < escolhido->carga)
                {
                    escolhido = aux;
                }
            }
        }
        return escolhido;
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't looked at all of this, but my first observation is that `scanf()` doesn't skip spaces (which include `'\n'`) unless you explicitly include them in the pattern, so it might not be reading your input correctly. Maybe check that first (e.g. try " %s" and " %s %s").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code:

```
        if (aux == header) // se o aux
        {
            header = aux->next;
            printf("%d ", aux->carga);
            (aux->next)->prev = NULL;  // crash here with aux->next == NULL
            aux->next = NULL;
            free(aux);
            return header;
        }
```

when you are removing the last element (`aux` == `header`), `aux->next` is `NULL` and attempting to dereference it causes a crash. You must check that `aux->next != NULL` before doing that.

P.S. The `aux->next = NULL` is useless if you immediately call `free(aux)`.